# How browser retrieve web page

Tags: dns, browser

I have little question about how web browser retrieve webpage?

I know this

> User request www.example.com **-->** web
>   browser resolve DNS of www.example.com
>   using DNS Server **-->** It got something
>   like 156.23.15.12 **-->** then web browser
>   request 156.23.15.12 **-->** It retrive
>   all document and render web page and
>   display it to user. Am I right?

Now My Question is, is web broswer request ISP to resolve DNS and than directly take to the server. **OR** is it request **only** IP or that domain and then retrive web page with the IP?

I think you can understood what I want to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're asking whether 1) your computer resolves the name and then connects directly to the web server's IP **OR** 2) your computer only sends a request to your ISP and then waits for the ISP to download the page for you?

In general, your computer connects directly to the web server.

It's also possible to connect to an intermediate server which does everything for you - resolves the name, connects to the end server, downloads content and then sends it back to your ocmputer. That intermediate computer is called an [HTTP proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Http_proxy).

So if I understood your question, it depends on how your network is set up. The most common setup is 1) without a proxy.

Comment: Thanks Martin, Exactly what I want to know.

Comment: Hi, Martin. I have one another question which setting is best from above both option?

Comment: Bad question because it depends on your requirments. Define "best". Fastest? Less expesnive? More control?